# Exclude whole group based on single value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012, group-by

Table T

```
CID Code
1    A
1    B
1    C
2    C
2    A
2    B
3    A
3    D
```

I want the output to have only those CID groups where `Code <> 'C'`

Desired Output:

```
CID  Code
3     A
3     D
```

Query Attempt:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
         CID
        ,Code
FROM Table T
WHERE Code <> 'C'
```

But this will exclude rows where Code = C, not the entire groups where Code = C.
Not sure how `GROUP BY` could work here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method uses `not exists`:

```
select distinct cid, code
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.cid = t.cid and t2.code = 'C'
                 );
```

Another method uses a window function:

```
select distinct cid, code
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when t.code = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by cid) as numCs
      from t
     ) t
where numCs = 0;
```

Comment: Could you please explain how WHERE NOT EXISTS excludes the entire CID group if even one record has 'C' in it. And not just individual rows from that group with 'C' in it?

Comment: @AS91 . . . The correlation clause says that if any record with the same `CID` has a code of `'C'`, then `NOT EXISTS` will filter it out.

Answer (score 5):

One more variant, which produces the same execution plan as the one with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT T.CID, T.Code
FROM T
WHERE
    T.CID NOT IN
    (
        SELECT T2.CID
        FROM T AS T2
        WHERE T2.Code = 'C'
    )
;
```

Inner query gives a list of all CID groups that have at least one `C`. Main query returns all rows from all other groups, not included in the inner list.

I don't understand why you put `DISTINCT` in the query. If the data doesn't have duplicates, `DISTINCT` would do extra sort that does nothing useful, since there are no duplicates already. If the data has duplicates - do you really want to get rid of them?

Comment: As confident as I am for the results not having duplicates (in the non-simplified version of this problem), I generally use it to ensure there are none when I get 100+ rows.